# Steam is extremely slow to load the first game

Tags: steam

It takes almost 4 minutes to start a game (Dota2) and another 3 to start a match after accepting a match. this always happens only on my first match. The subsequent matches load relatively quickly, but when i quit the game. My entire system is slowed down for some reason and it stays this way till I restart the computer. My computer configuration is enough to play the game at basic graphics.

Comment: `My computer configuration is enough to play the game at basic graphics.` What are they?

Comment: Its my Sony Vaio laptop.The configuration isIntel core i3-2330M processor 2 GB RAM. Geforce 410M

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get install htop`. Then you can open `htop` in your terminal just before you open steam. Then look at what process are using your memory and CPU. Is all your memory used? Are you using swap? All that sort of stuff. Also can you recreate the problem with another steam game?

Comment: unfortunately i don't own any other game in steam. No, all the memory is not being used. And by the way what is swap?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I installed steam. The game was DreadOut (I wouldn't recommend it) and it used to take a couple of minutes displaying a black screen before the game actually started.

What I have done is install the graphic card manager in order to optimize the gaming settings.

I don't know what graphic card you have but in my case it was an AMD and I have ubuntu 14.04 so I installed Catalyst control center using this video

==> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka5gBMlo-zo

Optimize my gaming settings and then the problem was over.

I hope this helps,

Regards

Comment: This is not an answer to user247473's problem.  This is more a comment as you don't know whether he/she has the same video card as you...  Please delete your answer and add a comment asking him what kind of GPU he has and also ask about his system RAM. (hunch)